# nginx refuses connections after some time

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, cron, connection

I have a problem with my nginx configuration, my server works fine but after 1 or 2 days it just hangs and stop responding. It's not possible to connect to the server anymore.

```
(7) Failed to connect to XX.XX.XX.XX port 80: Connection refused
```

The main job of this server is running heavy PHP tasks, I run cron jobs every 5 seconds for many tasks. Restart helps and again nginx works correctly for the next 1-2 days. I don't have any error logs, nginx dosn't report anything in /var/log/nginx/error.log. It simply fails all connections. Any ideas where to start looking for a problem?

I run nginx on Ubuntu 16.04, 2 CPUs, 4 GB ram with PHP 7.0.
nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)

here is config file:

```
 user www-data;
 worker_processes 2;
 pid /run/nginx.pid;

 events {
  worker_connections 4096;
  #multi_accept on;
 }

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 300;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

here is default file:

```
server {
 large_client_header_buffers 4 128k;
 listen XX:XX:XX:XX:80;

 set $root_path '/var/www/web/public/';

 root $root_path;
 index index.php;

 server_name XX:XX:XX:XX;

 location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
 }

 location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 14400;

    proxy_set_header   Connection "";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
 }

 location /status {
        stub_status on;
        access_log  off;
        allow XX:XX:XX:XX;
        deny all;
 }

 location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
    root $root_path;
 }

 # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
 # concurs with nginx's one
 location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
 }
}
```

And the main thing, my cron jobs I run, for example:

```
* * * * * sleep 5; curl --request GET http://XX:XX:XX:XX/queue/fire > /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 10; curl --request GET http://XX:XX:XX:XX/queue/fire > /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 15; curl --request GET http://XX:XX:XX:XX/queue/fire > /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 20; curl --request GET http://XX:XX:XX:XX/queue/fire > /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 25; curl --request GET http://XX:XX:XX:XX/queue/fire > /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 30; curl --request GET http://XX:XX:XX:XX/queue/fire > /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 35; curl --request GET http://XX:XX:XX:XX/queue/fire > /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 40; curl --request GET http://XX:XX:XX:XX/queue/fire > /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 45; curl --request GET http://XX:XX:XX:XX/queue/fire > /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 50; curl --request GET http://XX:XX:XX:XX/queue/fire > /dev/null 2>&1
```

etc.

**UPDATE:**

PHP FPM Status

```
 * php7.0-fpm.service - The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.0-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-01-13 10:46:41 CET; 3 days ago
  Process: 1439 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/php/php7.0-fpm-checkconf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1662 (php-fpm7.0)
   Status: "Processes active: 0, idle: 25, Requests: 164215, slow: 0, Traffic: 0req/sec"
    Tasks: 26
   Memory: 377.3M
      CPU: 5h 57min 32.279s
   CGroup: /system.slice/php7.0-fpm.service
           |- 1662 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)                      
           |- 1752 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |- 8751 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-12078 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-14053 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-14338 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-14639 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-14763 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-16188 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-16212 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-16900 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-17620 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-17621 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-17766 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-18802 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-19084 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-22064 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-24245 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-24690 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-25120 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-27714 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-29415 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-30182 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-30391 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           |-32053 php-fpm: pool www                                                            
           `-32358 php-fpm: pool www                                                            

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would check php fpm logs. Maybe running out of php fpm processes.

Comment: thanks! just checked it and I have many warnings `WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), 
consider raising it.` I forgot about default settings, Im gonna increase it and see if it helps.

Comment: it didn't help ;/ I changed from default to: `pm.max_children = 40 and pm.start_servers = 15 and pm.min_spare_servers = 15 and pm.max_spare_servers = 25 and pm.max_requests = 500`. After 2 days I had the same problem, no more errors about children and no errors from nginx ;/ any ideas?

Comment: That's the only thing I can think of that would cause that behavior. I suggest turning on access and error logs for both NGINX and php-fpm and tracing the failed requests.

Comment: I updated config files, so I will try to track it next time. I just had again the same situation, my nginx just stopped responding. I checked php-fpm status and updated my main post. No idea why I have idle: 25 in Status.. Maybe my PHP is doing something nasty, because I have heavy PHP tasks, they may take up to 1-2 hours, so I set always in PHP `set_time_limit(14400); ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` Maybe something here is not correct .. What is interesting, whenever i restart nginx everything works correctly... it looks like nginx problem.

Comment: There are some fastcgi timeout settings you can play with, such as fastcgi_read_timeout: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_read_timeout

Comment: I will try play with it, what I noticed in access logs which i had turned on few days ago, that nginx doesn't write any logs in this time when I could not connect, here is a log for example: `XX:XX:XX:XX - - [12/Jan/2017:16:25:59 +0100] "GET /queue/fire HTTP/1.1" 200 36 "-" "curl/7.47.0"
XX:XX:XX:XX - - [12/Jan/2017:22:19:18 +0100] "GET /queue/fire HTTP/1.1" 200 36 "-" "curl/7.47.0"` It is just a huge gap, although my cron was trying to run tasks, nginx was refusing connections "Failed to connect to XX.XX.XX.XX port 80: Connection refused", I restarted nginx at 22:19 and it run again.